# Is there a way to insert CTE output into a #mytemp in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am having difficulty inserting my CTE into a #mytemp table

```
DECLARE @dt1 Datetime='2012-08-01'
DECLARE @dt2 Datetime= (SELECT DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()),0))

;WITH ctedaterange 
     AS (SELECT [rn]=Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
         FROM   sys.objects a 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects b 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects c 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects d) 
SELECT Dateadd(dd, rn, @dt1) 
INTO #PROP_TABLE
FROM   ctedaterange 
WHERE  [rn] <= Datediff(dd, @dt1, @dt2)
```

Comment: So what is the problem precisely?

Comment: Since you are creating a table, you must name the columns in said table by giving any expressions in your select a column alias (e.g. `Dateadd(dd, rn, @dt1)  AS DateColumn`). As an aside, it helps if you are a bit more descriptive with your issue. Rather than simply saying "I am having difficulty", say what the difficulty is, e.g. "I am getting an error when I run the script" (then include the error), or "The script runs, but I don't get the results I expecting" (then include the results you are getting, and the results you are expecting).

Comment: I am trying to run a query on a stock with a monthly snapshot of the stock position. so I want to create a temporary table that I can pass into my date variable in my query

Comment: Apologies for my poor description ( I am fairly new to the platform- though not an excuse). @GarethD thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you did not alias you column. you need to give the column a name as below else it will not work as all table need a column name to be stated

```
DECLARE @dt1 Datetime='2012-08-01'
DECLARE @dt2 Datetime= (SELECT DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM, 0, GETDATE()),0))

;WITH ctedaterange 
     AS (SELECT [rn]=Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
         FROM   sys.objects a 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects b 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects c 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects d) 
SELECT Dateadd(dd, rn, @dt1) AS [Date] --- Insert a column Name here

INTO #PROP_TABLE

FROM   ctedaterange 
WHERE  [rn] <= Datediff(dd, @dt1, @dt2)

SELECT * FROM  #PROP_TABLE

DROP TABLE  #PROP_TABLE
```